# ColorPrimaryDark StatusBar Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am really getting crazy! I set in styles.xml and styles-v21.xml the attrs colorPrimaryDark and android:colorPrimaryDark but my statusBar does not change the color. I am using AppCompat-v22. Any idea?

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/brand_color</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/brand_color_dark</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabs</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/brand_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/brand_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/brand_color</item>
    <item name="android:seekBarStyle">@style/SeekBarAppTheme</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/activity_animations</item>
</style>
```

styles-v21.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/brand_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/brand_color_dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Show your code, please.

Comment: done! I really dont understand

Comment: So which theme did you post? The `styles.xml` one or the `styles-v21.xml` one (I assume you mean `-v21`, instead of just `-21`)?

Comment: Given that he's using AppCompat, I hope he posted `styles.xml`. @YamiFraiman, please post both your `styles*` xml files, and label them.

Comment: Yes, sorry I mean styles-v21.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your status bar color can only change in API 21+. In older devices, Android doesn't allow the developer to touch that attribute. [Read this article, in Theming part](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html):

> When you set these attributes, AppCompat automatically propagates their values to the framework attributes on API 21+. This automatically colors the status bar and Overview (Recents) task entry.
>
> On older platforms, AppCompat emulates the color theming where
>   possible. At the moment this is limited to coloring the action bar and
>   some widgets.

Hence, I think you tested with device < API 21, you should try with newer OS device.

Comment: Last month I used the same style in another app and it works perfectly in my phone (api 19)

Comment: look at what is said in the article: On older platforms, AppCompat emulates the color theming `where possible` . Not everytime it will success. It is really depend on the device and you should accept it.

Comment: I have the same code in other app and it works using the same device

Answer (score 0):

try add `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` on your `layout xml`'s root view

I have tried on **device > API 21 device** and found this attributes is necessary if you want change statusbar color

Answer (score 0):

just change your targetSdkVersion to 23